# Cannot resolve column [name] in Java using Microsoft SQL Server and Javax.Persistence

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc, jpa

One of my classes that convert table in SQL Server database to entities.

```java
    @Id
    @Column(name = "[primary_key]")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "[id Employee]")
    private byte[] employeeId;
    @Column(name = "[Period]")
    private Date period;
    @Column(name = "[Credit amount]")
    private float creditAmount;
    @Column(name = "[Type]")
    private String type;
    @Column(name = "[Weight 585]")
    private float weight585;
```

and CrudRepo for it (partial):

```java
@Query(value = "select sum([Weight 585]) from [ZOK per period] where ([Period] between ?1 and ?2) " +
            "and ([id Employee] = ?3) and ([Type] = 'Gold')", nativeQuery = true)
    Double getSumZokGold(Date start, Date end, byte[] employeeId);
```

All my column names are red and underlined with two errors:

1. Cannot resolve column '';
2. Unknown database function '';

I checked persistence and data already assigned - its most popular solution of this problem. I checked dialect - SQL Server, already. I checked ALL column names and didn't see any mistake.

Comment: I'd like to note that i use [] in column names because customer sometimes use russian 'One-C' and i need to be able to create columns with names on russian and earlier, before updating IntelliJ IDEa to version 2019.3, it used to work.

Comment: If you are about IDE issue I don't think that's something which worth some efforts.

Comment: @AlexeyUsharovski, as I can see, its just problem on IDEa-side, because my SQL-queries work correctly, but this issue creates problems while I am writing new queries.

Comment: This problem is missing on my laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve this problem you may do:**

1. Check all columns names - yes, problem can be just in it. *By the way, you will have an Error if its true.*
2. Add new Database in `Database` (right IDE side) and connect to your data source.
3. Check your `Persistence` (bottom left corner in "Intellij IDEa"), press `Assign Data...` and use in `Data Source` not default source, but exactly yours.
4. If you have already connected database (MS Server, for example) - reconnect. Yes, its useful too.
5. Now, if your problem still annoying you - open `File - Invalidate Caches / Restart` and choose blue button **Invalidate and Restart**.

P.S.: If you use russian names for your table columns in database - write them as `@Column(name = "[...]")` and in SQL `@Query` put N before value in "" or write name in brackets. **But the best idea - use just English!**